# Retrieve image and show it without exposing its path in web container

Tags: jsp, captcha

In my college JSP project, for registration of user I'm using CAPTCHA-like authentication, and I have some images which have simple mathematical challenges (Eg. 2 * 5 = ?). Note that I'm not using any third-party APIs like reCAPTCHA for such requirement as it'll need my project to have internet access which I can't have during our project demo.

Now, I'll be loading any of the image from my collection randomly on modal dialog when user clicks submit from registration form. So, what is the preferred way to load the image such that user cannot see the real path of image (Eg. `<img src="/captcha-images/img2343.jpg"/>`) or is there any other preferred (bot-safe) way to perform such user verification without using images or any third-party libraries. I know in real webapps, such libraries are used but I mentioned the reason of not using any such.

Answer (score 2):

What you will generally do is get the image via a call to a dynamic page.  An img tag can accept any type of URL, what's important is the header being returned by the call.

So, you could use the URL of

```
<img src="/captcha-images/security.action"/>
```

just as an example.  As long as security.action returned something that appeared to the browser to be an image, it would be rendered as an image.

Inside security.action, you would have all the logic to generate the right image based on the current session, and to make sure that the captcha verification had the proper credentials.